# Does encapsulating a quantity in a struct for type safety have performance implications?

Tags: c#, performance, struct, units-of-measurement

I use this convention (inspired by F#'s units) to catch certain classes of programming errors:

```
public struct Inch : IComparable<Inch>
{
    public readonly float Value;
    public Inch(int value) : this() { Value = value; }
    public static implicit operator Inch(float value) { return new Inch(value); }
    public int CompareTo(Inch other) { return Value.CompareTo(other.Value); }
    public override string ToString() { return Value.ToString(); }
}
```

Operations such as addition are performed thusly:

```
Inch a, b;
Inch result = a.Value + b.Value;
```

This allows `Inch` to be passed with the low overhead of a value type, with the advantage that it cannot be accidentally assigned to a plain `float`. (I've found that allowing implicit conversion in the opposite direction i.e., of floats to `Inch`es, does not typically result in bugs.)

Question: Are there known performance issues **specifically** with the example of addition shown. Again this question is only about performance, I have no questions about the semantics.

Comment: To those who voted to close citing overly broad, I've reworded the question to be very narrow.

Comment: Your question is not narrow.  You're very specifically *not* narrowing it to a given context.  If you were, you could profile the code in that context and find out for yourself if it's a problem.  You're asking how the code will perform *in every single context that could possibly exist*, which is of course unanswerable due to scope.

Comment: No, I am not asking that. I am asking if there are *known issues* with this type of approach, not a blanket validation. I assume the risk of using this code. :)

Comment: How is that narrowing the scope at all?  Asking for any *known* problems that could Rocco in any possible context isn't any more reasonable.

Comment: No, posting a huge block of code and saying "please fix" wouldn't be appropriate.  Posting a reasonably scoped block of code, explaining how it is currently behaving, how it should behave, and describing in detail what you've done to this point in attempting to diagnose the problem, could have a shot.  I'm not familiar enough with CR to comment on it's ontopicness there.

Comment: We tried something like that in one of our applications, but the cost was too high (2x to 5x overhead with basic operations like addition), so we backed up. But there was *a lot* of computations going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest semantic problem here is the use of an `implicit` operator, which allows any `float` value to be treated as an `Inch` unit. You should remove that operator, or change it to be `explicit`.

The biggest performance concern is the lack of overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods. You should override both of these methods on the [default implementation provided by `ValueType` which may be slower slower](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dts52z7.aspx). Some runtime environments may detect that the class does not directly or indirectly contain any fields with reference types and provide an efficient implementation of these methods, but no guarantee is made regarding this.

For additional usability, you could define an `operator +` which performs the addition, so you could have the following:

```
Inch a, b;
Inch result = a + b;
```

Naturally, the same applies for `operator -`.

Theoretically, the struct could have performance overhead approaching zero, but it will be dependent on many aspects of the runtime environment, *especially* the ability to inline methods. The final answer to whether or not the overhead is observable and/or acceptable can only be determined by profiling the use of the type in the expected environments with the expected inputs.

Comment: I don't have an issue with the semantics, as mentioned; the approach does in fact catch bugs. Could you please explain why you believe the default implementation of Equals and GetHashCode is slower? There is only one field, so I'd expect performance to equal that of a plain float.

Comment: @bright I have updated my answer with additional references, but my concern over the semantics of the implicit operator are sufficiently strong that I would be uncomfortable providing an answer without including a statement advising against it.

Comment: After reading the link I see what you mean about Equals and GetHashCode - a byte by byte comparison may be slower than an optimized float comparison. In that case - what implementation of Equals will give the same performance as float? The casting involved in Value.Equals(((Inch)other).Value) seems like it might be inefficient.

Comment: FYI here's why this approach works. Let's say an Inch and a Meter are initialized somewhere (from floats), and pass through a bunch of code (with type safety) before one is assigned to the other. This approach will catch the bug, whereas if both were floats the bug would not be found. Assigning from naked floats can only be done by explicitly specifying Inch, i.e. Inch foo = 5; You cannot use "var" here. Similarly an operation like Inch result = a.Value + b.Value clearly indicates something unusual. The only case that isn't caught is passing a float to a function that accepts an Inch.

Comment: @bright `Meter x, y; Inch result = x.Value + y.Value;`. If `x` and `y` are declared in another scope which is out of view, the reviewer cannot determine if the addition is semantically correct.

Comment: You don't need to go overboard with `Equals(object)`, because either `operator==` or `Equals(Inch)` would be used in performance-sensitive contexts.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the following code in LINQPad 4 with full optimizations:

```
    struct IntWrapper
    {
        readonly int x;

        public IntWrapper(int x)
        {
            this.x = x;
        }

        //[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)] doesn't seem to matter
        public static implicit operator IntWrapper(int x)
        {
            return new IntWrapper(x);
        }

        //[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)] doesn't seem to matter
        public static IntWrapper operator +(IntWrapper x, IntWrapper y)
        {
            return new IntWrapper(x.x + y.x);
        }
    }

    void Main()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        var xs = new List<int>(500);
        var mode = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        for (var j = 0; j < 500; j++)
        {
            sw.Start();

            for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                var x = random.Next();
                var y = random.Next();

                var z = x + y;
            }

            sw.Stop();

            var elasped = (int)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            xs.Add(elasped);

            int count;

            if(!mode.TryGetValue(elasped, out count))
                mode.Add(elasped, 1);
            else
                mode[elasped] = count + 1;

            Console.WriteLine(elasped);

            sw.Reset();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(xs.Average());
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Sqrt(xs.Select(x => Math.Pow(x, 2)).Sum() / (xs.Count())));

        var max = 0;
        var key = 0;

        foreach (var memo in mode)
            if(memo.Value > max)
            {
                max = memo.Value;
                key = memo.Key;
            }

        Console.WriteLine(key);

    }
```

In the cases of both `System.Int32` and `IntWrapper` I observed an average (mean) of about `30ms` and a mode of `25ms` on 500 trials.

Interestingly, I recall reading somewhere that the `readonly` modifier on `ValueType` fields of a ValueType` class incurs a performance hit, but I observed no such penalty in this experiment.